# How to add two css files conditionally in one component on Angular 8

Tags: css, angular, typescript, forms, angular8

The component contains a form, and I want to use two languages and each one its own CSS style, one for direction: ltr; and the other direction: rtl;

How can I conditionally use 2 CSSs files on the component?

This component contains a dialog display,

```
  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.dialog.open(chooseLanguageComponent); 
  }
```

so the user can choose which language likes if user chooses English form the component use style1.css and if he chooses Arabic English the component use style2.css

I use angular 8 / Angular material / NG-ZORRO

Comment: Given the way that Angular AOT compiles the CSS into the component, you can't dynamically use different css files. You could, however, add a class of the language to the form, and then that class could change the look of the nested elements.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just use classes into the body for that.

When you change the language to add for example ".rtl" or ".ltr" class to the body, then the style related each alignment should be preceded with the class name, something like this.

```
.rtl p {
  text-align: right;
}
.ltr p {
  text-align: left;
}
```